# PhoneGap on click backbutton simulate click in home button

Tags: android, cordova, back-button, android-homebutton

I'm looking for change action for backbutton, actually I'm using events to catch backbutton calls and using `navigator.app.exitApp();` to close app (in really pause app), but I need backbutton call action like home button.

Why? Well, I using cordova-plugin-background-mode, and this works only when app send to background (if using navigator.app.appExit() app is paused), so I need leave app every in background.

Is possible change action of backbutton to works like home?

I want use in iPhone and Android systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the plugin

https://github.com/amitsinha559/cordova-plugin-back-as-home

and

https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize

after adding the plugin you can minimize the app when ever you want
like on back button click

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
    window.plugins.appMinimize.minimize();
}
```

Whichever suits you. Unfortunately they both are for android. you need to create plugin manually for iPhone.

Comment: Link can be vanish ! You should post as a comment instead of answer !